# Is there a way to run Windows 8 Apps on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-8, emulation

Many Windows 8 desktop applications can be ran on Linux via Wine.

I really don't know how to run application download from the store on a Linux box. The way the programs are packaged is an immediate problem, and I have not had any success in executing the binaries.

Does anybody know of any works in progress for this kind of functionality?

Comment: The only reason some desktop applications even work on Wine is because the support was added.  You will have to wait until Wine supports the WinRT library before what you want is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say but there is simply no way of doing this.

The reason is also quite simple as Windows Store is a Microsoft's innovation for Microsoft's OS users.

Although you will find most of the Windows DESKTOP APPS for Linux from Linux store or some third party sites.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK The only solution for now is virtual box or vmware.Use one of these and install a copy in that.Then you can use windows store apps on linux.